# List from List Streams JAVA8

Tags: list, java-8, java-stream

I need go through a list(class A) from lists(classB). I want to use streams JAVA8, but go through the second list i lose the reference from first list

```
class A {
   Collection<B> listB ;
   String x;
   // Some other variables
}

class B {
   String y;
   // Some other variables
}

// List object A

Collection<class A> listA;

listA.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getListaB() != null)
    .flatMap(a -> a.getListB().stream())
    .forEach(b -> {
                // Here lose reference object A
                // I need something like a.getX()
                // I need too use something like b.getY(), use both lists
                    });
```

The error is "cannot find simbol variable a" I understand the error, There is any solutions use streams and not foreach or for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't nest the second stream to the first one but you flatten it :

```
.flatMap(a -> a.getListB().stream())
```

So finally after this statement you get simply a `stream<B>` of all elements of `List`s of `B`.

To solve you requirement, nest the stream and use `forEach()` instead of `flatMap()` as here you don't want to transform anything but you want to apply a `Consumer` :

```
Collection<A> listA = ...;

listA.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getListaB() != null)
    .forEach(a -> a.getListB().stream()
               .forEach(b -> {
                    // a and b are usable now
                })
       );
```

Comment: Thank you so much.